# Android app has large cache?

Tags: android, caching

I recently checked the cache of the app I am a developer for and noticed that the cache is around 17 MB after about 2 weeks of daily usage on my Galaxy Nexus.

The app pulls down JSON and displays it in a `ListView` in one Activity, and the other Activity displays a `WebView`. I currently do not store any JSON in the Android cache. What could be in the cache? Does the OS save it's own data in my app's cache?

Comment: Hey there, I have a similarly structured app (5 listviews 1 webview in 3 tabs) that has a cached size of 47mb on my galaxy nexus.  Have you resolved this issue?

Comment: I haven't resolved it. I thought it may have been due to me using a custom View at one point, but common sense is leading me to believe it's the WebViews.

Comment: Have you saved anything using getCacheDir()? And did you use any 3rd-party library for advertising?

Comment: AdMob advertising, yes

Answer (score 2):

The OS will keep your process alive and not clear anything out unless it needs the resources. From [the guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#InternalCache):

> When the device is low on internal storage space, Android may delete these cache files to recover space. However, you should not rely on the system to clean up these files for you. You should always maintain the cache files yourself and stay within a reasonable limit of space consumed, such as 1MB. When the user uninstalls your application, these files are removed.

You aren't saving JSON files in the cache, but are you saving anything else?

Comment: I'm not saving anything directly in to the cache. My current theory is that the WebViews are storing data in the cache and not clearing it.